# HTML Canvas brush is doing additional lines

Tags: html, canvas, html5-canvas

I am doing an image coloring web application with React and I am using html canvas for drawing. The problem is that the brush is sometimes doing these strange lines to coordinates where I didn't put the mouse. The mouse strokes I wanted to color are marked with the blue line, and the additional strokes that I don't want are circled with a yellow marker.

So my question is: How to solve the problem of the brush drawing additional strokes to points where I didn't put my mouse?

[image]

Linecap style:

```
Context.lineCap = "round"
```

The code for drawing is:

```
const drawMove = (clientX: number, clientY: number) => {
    if (!isDrawing) {
        return;
    }

    if (DrawCanvasRef.current) {
        const Canvas = DrawCanvasRef.current;
        const Context = Canvas.getContext("2d");

        if (Context) {
            const { x, y } = getMousePos(DrawCanvasRef, clientX, clientY);

            if (x && y) {
                Context.lineTo(x, y);
                Context.stroke();
            }
        }
    }
};
```

Other functions:

```
const startDrawing = (clientX: number, clientY: number) => {
    if (DrawCanvasRef.current) {
        const Canvas = DrawCanvasRef.current;
        const Context = Canvas.getContext("2d");

        if (Context) {
            // Get current mouse positions
            const { x, y } = getMousePos(DrawCanvasRef, clientX, clientY);

            // If mouse position is allright, then begin line path
            if (x && y) {
                Context.beginPath();
                Context.moveTo(x, y);
                setIsDrawing(true);
            }
        }
    }
};

const touchMove = (event: TouchEvent) => {
    drawMove(
        event.nativeEvent.touches[0].clientX,
        event.nativeEvent.touches[0].clientY
    );
};

const mouseMove = (event: MouseEvent) => {
    drawMove(event.nativeEvent.clientX, event.nativeEvent.clientY);
};

const finishDrawing = () => {
    if (DrawCanvasRef.current && HiddenCanvasRef.current) {
        const Canvas = DrawCanvasRef.current;
        const HiddenCanvas = HiddenCanvasRef.current;
        const Context = Canvas.getContext("2d");
        const HiddenContext = HiddenCanvas.getContext("2d");

        if (Context && HiddenContext) {
            // Stop drawing the path
            Context.closePath();
            setIsDrawing(false);

            HiddenContext.drawImage(Canvas, 0, 0, CANVAS_WIDTH, CANVAS_HEIGHT);

            clearCanvas(DrawCanvasRef);
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: Maybe set the lineCap style to `'round'`? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/lineCap

Comment: Hi, it is already set to round, but not in this part which I pasted here, but it was a good suggestion

Comment: @Calculuswhiz Weird thing is that it somehow started to work when I was trying out other styles and switched it back to round now, so thank you

Comment: Can you add a jsfiddle or code snippet to your question so we can see what's going on?

Comment: It is a complex project with a lot of files and exporting, I can add other functions for drawing. Now the problem is only when the brush is going one side, and then in a very similar path to the beginning of the path. Earlier it was with all kinds of strokes